# Does ZF+AD settle the original Suslin hypothesis?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, determinacy

Everyone knows that the real line $\langle\mathbb{R},<\rangle$ is
the unique endless complete dense linear order with a countable
dense set. [Suslin's
hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem) is
the question whether we can replace separability in this
characterization with the assertion that the order has the
countable chain condition, that is, that every set of disjoint
intervals is countable. In other words, Suslin's hypothesis, in the
original formulation, is the assertion that the real line is the
unique endless complete dense linear order with the countable chain
condition.

**Question.** Does ZF plus the [axiom of determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) AD imply the original Suslin hypothesis?

Set theorists proved in ZFC that Suslin's hypothesis is equivalent
to the assertion that there is no Suslin tree, which is a tree of
height $\omega_1$ with no uncountable chains or antichains. And ZF plus the
axiom of determinacy AD settles this version of SH by proving that
$\omega_1$ is measurable and hence weakly compact and hence has the
tree property and so under AD there is there is no
Suslin tree.

So under AD there is no $\omega_1$-Suslin tree. But does this mean that there is no Suslin line?

The point is that refuting a Suslin tree does not seem directly to refute all Suslin lines in the non-AC context, and therefore it does not seem to settle the original Suslin problem under AD. So the question is: does
ZF+AD settle the original Suslin problem?

Please feel free to post an answer explaining the precise details
of the argument that AD implies there is no $\omega_1$-Suslin tree.

I heard this question this evening at a party at [a conference in
honor of Simon Thomas](http://www.grigorsargis.net/SimonFest.html)
from a certain prominent set theorist, aged Scotch in hand, who
told me that he would rather not be mentioned, but who said he was
fine for the question to be posted.

Let me update the question (after Asaf's very nice answer) to ask about the situation where we also have the axiom of dependent choice DC. And perhaps one really wants to know about the case in $L(\mathbb{R})$ under AD.

**Question.** Does ZF+AD+DC imply the original Suslin hypothesis?

**Question.** Does $L(\mathbb{R})$ have a Suslin line assuming AD?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the argument from measurable to weakly compact uses normal measures, right? If so, then the argument doesn't go through in ZF, as Bilinsky and Gitik have shown, it is consistent for a measurable cardinal not to have any normal measures.

Comment: (To comment on my last comment, in the context of AD it is true, however, that $\omega_1$ is a measurable carrying a normal measure, and therefore the argument goes through as usual, I was just making a comment on the formulation of the remark in the question...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does the argument need a normal measure? The one I have in mind just replicates the proof of König's lemma at $\omega$, building a branch through the tree by finding on each level a node with measure one many descendants in the tree. I think completeness is enough for this although, looking at it now, it seems to use dependent choice, so perhaps the argument doesn't work regardless.

Comment: @Miha: For some reason I recalled choosing a path along the ultrafilter, and somehow needing some normality assumption to get a uniform selection. But you're probably right, and some sort of DC is probably necessary here (probably even more than just [countable] DC).

Comment: A cautionary note: There are two ways to formulate the tree property for $\omega_1$. One talks about trees with $\omega_1$ nodes; the other about trees with $\omega_1$ levels. Since each level is countable, these are equivalent in ZFC, but I don't see the equivalence in just ZF. The proof that measurability implies the tree property is fine under the first formulation, but I don't see how to do it under the second.

Comment: @Andreas: It shouldn't be too hard, I think, to come up with examples for models where these two notions diverge. For example, take a homogeneous Suslin tree, then add it as a "generic structure" while preserving its initial segments. This should be a non-well-orderable Suslin tree.

Comment: Yes, my comment about measurable$\to$tree property$\to$no Suslin trees was too quick, since there are several subtle issues there. Let me reiterate my request for someone to post an answer showing that AD refutes Suslin trees.

Comment: Hi Joel, you may already be aware of this, but I saw on the arXiv this morning that your last question has been answered: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08201.pdf.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The question is now answered in [L(R ) with Determinacy Satisfies the Suslin Hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08201)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Regarding your first sentence, I was at the supermarket earlier this morning and asked a customer whether he knew that the real line ⟨R,<⟩ is the unique endless complete dense linear order with a countable dense set. To which he quickly said "no I don't" and walked away. How can this be?

Comment: @openletter.mousetail.nl To that I would reply as Socrates does to Meno. https://www.thoughtco.com/slave-boy-experiment-in-platos-meno-2670668#mntl-sc-block_1-0-5 (Or just insert "here" as in "Everyone here knows...")

Answer (score 23):

No. Because of silly reasons.

Recall that the powers of $\sf AD$ are quite limited to the world below $\Theta$. In particular, the proof that $\sf AD$ does not imply countable choice goes through adding a Dedekind-finite set somewhere very high up the von Neumann hierarchy. Where the reals cannot interfere.

Simply replicate this proof, but this time embed a copy of the Mostowski linear ordering, instead of any ol' Dedekind-finite set. This would result in a linear ordering whose order topology is strongly connected (and hence the order is complete), where every subset is a finite union of intervals, and the power set is Dedekind-finite. So in particular, every collection of pairwise disjoint intervals is finite.

(Note that to get Mostowski's ordering you'd need each point to be a set of sets of ordinals, rather than just a set of ordinals, so you need to force with something like $\operatorname{Add}(\kappa,\kappa\times\omega)$, and then group your generic subsets into collections of generic subsets indexed by the rational numbers, and take permutations which turn each "rational" into a sufficiently-non well-orderable set, and permutes the "rationals" in an order preserving way.

Of course, using any other method of adding generic sets, not necessarily Cohen subsets, also works for these purposes.)

---

Here is an outline of how to construct such model.

Start with a model of $\sf ZFC$ with $\omega$ Woodin cardinals, and for good posterity also $\sf GCH$. Pick some regular $\kappa$ much much larger than all the Woodin cardinals. For example, the double successor of their limit.

Next step, take the product of the two symmetric systems: (1) add a Mostowski order above $\kappa$, and let $\cal A$ denote the Mostowski ordering, along with its linear order; (2) collapse the Woodin cardinals to force $\sf AD$ in an inner model.

Finally, in the symmetric extension consider $L(\Bbb R,\cal A)$. By the closure of adding Cohen subsets to $\kappa$, and it being large enough, we have ensured that the set of reals in this models are all definable from reals, i.e. live in $L(\Bbb R)$. Therefore $\sf AD$ holds. At the same time, all the relevant arguments about the Mostowski ordering involve its power set being Dedekind-finite, which is true in the symmetric extension, and therefore in any inner model which knows the underlying set.

---

The answer is still negative even if one requires $\sf DC$ to hold. Indeed, we can generalize the above argument in the following way (which now requires assuming $\sf GCH$, or something similar about the continuum at regular cardinals):

1. By $\sf GCH$, $\eta_\kappa$ exists, which is a $\kappa$-saturated dense linear ordering of size $\kappa$. Therefore it is also homogeneous.
2. Instead of adding $\kappa\times\omega$ subsets of $\kappa$, we add $\kappa\times\kappa$, where the second $\kappa$ is indexed using a linear ordering isomorphic to $\eta_\kappa$. Now we take the filter of subgroups to be generated by fixing countably many points, rather than finitely many.
3. The technique and argument now give us that if $A$ is the generic linear ordering, every subset of $A$ is the countable union of intervals. This, along with the saturation of $\eta_\kappa$, readily implies that the order is complete.

   Given any cut, we can write it as the union of two intervals, they have a common support which is a countable set of points on the line. One can show that these points must have a cofinal sequence in the upper and lower parts of the cut (otherwise there is a "gap" between the cuts which can be moved by a suitable automorphism). And by saturation we can realize the type of the cut, and thus it is an endpoint of one of the parts of the cut.
4. The linear order we added is actually ccc, since any uncountable family of pairwise disjoint intervals would have a union which cannot be decomposed into only countably many disjoint intervals. Of course, the order is not separable, since $\kappa$ is just too darn big, and separability would imply that we collapsed $\kappa$ to be the continuum in the outset $\sf ZFC$ model, but $\kappa$ is in fact the successor of the continuum (or larger!), so that cannot be.
5. In $L(\Bbb R,\cal A^\omega)$, where $\cal A$ is the ordered set, as computed inside the symmetric extension of both the collapses of the Woodin cardinals, and adding the Mostowski $\sigma$-order, we get that $\sf ZF+DC+AD$ holds. But $\cal A$ is still a non-separable ccc and complete dense linear ordering. Therefore a counterexample.

---

So it seems like the real question is assuming that $L(\Bbb R)\models\sf AD$; does it also satisfies $\sf SH$? Or, perhaps, does $\sf ZF+AD+\mathit{V=L(\Bbb R)}\implies SH$?

Here I'm a bit more skeptical about how much the above ideas could work. And it actually seems to be plausible that there are no Suslin trees, in the broad sense of the word.

Comment: I'd expect, however, $\sf AD$ to solve the Suslin Hypothesis for sets below $\Theta$, or you know, below the power set of the reals.

Comment: Parson my ignorance, but what is $\theta$?

Comment: The least ordinal such that there is no surjection from the reals onto it. What I would normally call the Lindenbaum number of the reals.

Comment: Thanks very much for this post!  This seems to answer the question I had asked. But in truth, I had had in mind the case where we would also have DC, which I didn't state, and it seems that your technique would not work in that case.

Comment: @Joel: Indeed the case with DC is different. I shall give it some thought. But I generally believe that with the right linear order one can easily replicate this while preserving DC.

Comment: I would be very interested in that, if you can do it.

Comment: @Joel: Will do. Ask me again in a couple of days if I haven't gotten back to you.

Comment: @Joel: I think the proof would work with DC as I expected. I will try to write a sketch here later today when I am behind an actual keyboard.

Comment: @Joel: Let me know what you think about the edit.

Comment: @Asaf I'm confused by this statement, "I'd expect, however, AD to solve the Suslin Hypothesis for sets below Θ".

Comment: @NotMike: Which part confuses you?

Comment: @Asaf, Isn't it a theorem that a Suslin line will be as large as $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @NotMike: Not even if you assume choice.

Comment: @Asaf it's complete and dense in itself. What am I missing?

Comment: @NotMike: Yes, you're right of course, I thought about the switch from a tree to a line wrong. Actually looking back, I'm not entirely sure what I meant by below $\Theta$. Maybe in $V_\Theta$ or something.

Comment: @Asaf: how do you show AD holds in $L({\mathbb R},{\cal A}^\omega)$?

Comment: @Ralf: Every set of reals in the symmetric extension was added by the collapsing part. So $\cal A^\omega$ does not introduce any new sets reals that weren't there. Since $L(\Bbb R)$ satisfies $\sf AD$, it should work. No?

Comment: @Asaf: I can't follow. What is ${\cal A}^\omega$ then?

Comment: @Ralf: All the countable sequences of the generic copy of the linear order.

Comment: @Asaf: computed before or after the symm. collapse? If before: How does it help for DC? If after: Why couldn't you get new sets of reals?

Comment: @Ralf: After the symmetric extension (which include also the collapse). If you have a set of reals, constructible from some ordinal, real, and a countable sequence from $\cal A$, there is some condition forcing that. Let me write $x\in\varphi(p)$ to denote that $x$ is in the set defined by $\varphi(p)$. Now, if $p\Vdash\dot x\in\varphi(\check\gamma,\dot r,\dot f)$, where $\dot f$ is a sequence from $\cal A$, by homogeneity we can move $\dot f$ around without changing $\dot x,\dot r$ or $p$. So it was irrelevant for the definition. Am I cheating somewhere? (Probably?)

Comment: @Asaf: Sorry, I don't understand. It looks to me you're trying to show AD in the Chang model

Comment: @Ralf: I don't know about all that. I am only claiming that it would work with the countable sequences of the generic line. Not with countable sequences of ordinals. Although these, too, are only added by the collapses of the Woodin cardinals.

Answer (score 10):

Nice question! But which aged set theorist drinks prominent Scotch?

The following does not answer this question either. Let $T \in L$ be your favorite Suslin tree of $L$. Consider the $L({\mathbb R})$ of $L[g]$, where $g$ is generic for adding $\omega_1$ Cohen reals. $T$ is still a Suslin tree in $L[g]$. The set of all maximal branches thru $T$ is then a Suslin line in $L({\mathbb R})^{L[g]}$, and $L({\mathbb R})^{L[g]}$ is a model of ZF plus DC plus "there is no w.o. of the reals." So a Suslin line doesn't give a w.o. of ${\mathbb R}$.

As has been poited out, this approach can't be generalized to show that in the presence of large cardinals (or just ${\sf AD}^{L({\mathbb R})}$), $L({\mathbb R})$ has a Suslin line, as then no $T \in M$, $M$ any inner model of $L({\mathbb R})$ satisfying choice, can be an Aronzsajn tree in $L({\mathbb R})$.

But, assuming large cardinals, the question if $L({\mathbb R})$ has a Suslin line should have an answer as ${\sf ZFC}$ is $\Omega$-complete concerning truth in $L({\mathbb R})$.

Answer (score 9):

Concerning the existence of Suslin trees under $\mathsf{AD + V = L(\mathbb{R})}$:

Assume $ZF + AD^+ + V = L(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}))$. Let $(T,\prec)$ be an $\omega_1$-tree with all levels countable.

(I) Suppose $T$ is wellorderable. We can repeat Hamkin's argument above: One can show $T$ is in bijection with $\omega_1$. $(T,\prec)$ can be coded as a subset of $\omega_1$. $(T,\prec)$ is constructible from real $r$ by a result of Solovay; hence, $(T,\prec) \in L[r]$. $r^\sharp$ exists, so $\omega_1^V$ is weakly compact and has the tree property. Therefore, in $L[r]$, $T$ has a branch which is in bijection with $\omega_1^V$. $(T,\prec)$ is not a Suslin tree in $V$.

(II) Suppose $T$ can not be wellordered. By Theorem 1.4 of "A Trichotomy Theorem in Natural Models of $\mathsf{AD}^+$" by Caicedo and Ketchersid, there is an injection $\Phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow T$ under these assumptions. Define a prewellordering on $\mathbb{R}$ by $x \sqsubseteq y$ if and only if the level of $(T,\prec)$ that $\Phi(x)$ belongs to is less than or equal to the level of $(T,\prec)$ that $\Phi(y)$ belongs to. Since $(T,\prec)$ has countable levels, $\sqsubseteq$ is a prewellordering on $\mathbb{R}$ with each prewellordering class countable. This does not exists under $\mathsf{AD}$.